# Keyboard frame origin appears to be (0,0) when rotating to landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uikeyboard, cgrect

I'm trying to make a UIView appear just above the keyboard and make sure it keeps the correct positioning when the view rotates to landscape, but when I get the frame of the keyboard when it rotates to landscape, the frame is: {{0, 0}, {162, 568}}. Obviously, the Y value of the origin should not be 0 as the keyboard is not at the top of the screen. How can I translate the frame it gives me for the keyboard into a CGRect I can properly use in the landscape orientation?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Implement following implementation in your method

```
if (self.view.bounds.size.width == 480)
{ // choose more appropriate method to detect landscape mode then the one specified here.

    /* Here we are calculating keyboard origin y by subtracting keyboard frame's width as
     * when the device is rotated to landscape, the keyboard device width and height 
     * appeared to be interchanged implicity but the keyboard's bounds still explicitly 
     * shows portrait bounds, so we are subtracting self.view.bounds size height 
     * with keyboard frame width
     */

    float keyboardOriginY = self.view.bounds.size.height - keyboardFrame.size.width;
    float delta = 30;  // Subtract with whatever delta value you want to position above keyboard frame
    keyboardFrame.origin.y = keyboardOriginY - delta;
    keyboardFrame.size.height = delta;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:keyboardFrame];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```